# Codesign verification failed in Xcode for iphone app distribution

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate, distribution

I am trying to prepare my app for distribution to the app store and am getting the following warning in Xcode which is causing an error in ApplicationLoader. I know this is a common problem from searching but I have yet to find a proper solution? I went thru Apple's steps for distribution on the iOS provisioning portal and still get this error.

My distribution profile is set on my Target.

"Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

1) Check for the scheme in 4.2 
2) make sure you have  selected the release scheme 
3) make sure you have selected the distribution profile 
4) build for archiving .

Answer (score 0):

App distribution certificate is only used for the app store. You will get this error if you try and put an app signed with your distribution certificate on your phone -- it simply won't work.

Comment: correct. I am not trying to load the app to my device, I am just trying to build it and upload it to the store with ApplicationLoader.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a valid iPhone Distribution certificate in your Keychain?

Does the Xcode Organizer Provisioning Profile window show your Distribution provision?

Does your distribution provisioning profile have an app ID that is the same or compatible (wildcard) with the Identifier setting in your Target Info Properties setting?

Edit: added:

Do you have exactly one iPhone Distribution certificate in your Keychain?

Did you do a Build Clean in Xcode before your distribution build?  (or rm -rf ./build)

Comment: 1) Yes the status of the certificate says "valid"

Comment: 2) The distribution provision is there
3) In my info.plist file the bundle identifier is set to the appID seen in the provisioning portal for my app

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your Certificate, is it distribution or developer? And it must be Distribution certificate.

Follow these steps:

1. clean all certificate from your keychain and download new distribution certificate.
2. Also clean remove the distribution provisioning profile what you use for the particular for your this application and re download that one. after that must be clean build in Xcode and after that in project setting you must be select the particular D.P.P. for your application and go a head just only build it. then you get the particular build.
3. Regarding the D.P.P you must be clear what type of profile you create for this. it must be Appstore D.P.P.

I hope it should be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. For me it turns out that I didn't download the "distribution" provisioning file (note the emphasis on the "distribution"). Once I got that, everything worked. I'm almost certain that that's what your problem is ;)

cheers,
Matt