# upgraded xcode to the 4.2 "The signature was invalid"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, xcode4.2, provisioning-profile

Since I upgraded xcode to the 4.2 version I can't update my app any longer. 
I get the following error:  warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)

I've tried the following things to try to fix this problem,but it did not work:

- I re-downloaded provisional files (both distribution and development) from the web and I reuploaded them
- I completely uninstalled Xcode and reinstalled it
- I recreated the provisional files

Unfortunately I had no luck. What I'm supposed to do in order to continue developing iPhone apps?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Offhand there are two possibilities:

1. Sometimes you need to just reset the settings in the project. Go to the project's "code signing identity" settings and make sure the value is valid. Even if it appears valid it might not be. Try some of the other possible settings and see if they work.
2. It might be that your certificates are expired. If your developer program has expired you'll have to renew it, but the developer certificates all expire at some point and need to be renewed.

Comment: 1. I try all the value that appears but nothing.

Comment: Hmm. Try some of the other answers on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879473/how-to-fix-failed-codesign-verification-of-an-iphone-project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892148/application-failed-codesign-verification-what-do-i-do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415043/how-to-solve-this-problem-the-signature-was-invalid-or-it-was-not-signed-with-a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774546/codesign-verification-failed-in-xcode-for-iphone-app-distribution